# Provide feedback to event caller using writable property in EventArgs

Tags: c#, .net, events, reflection

In Dustin Campbell's answer in question [Return a value from a Event — is there a Good Practice for this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1210026/return-a-value-from-a-event-is-there-a-good-practice-for-this) it is stated that instead of returning data from an event handler, we can have a **writable property on a set of custom EventArgs that is passed to the event** similar to Cancel property of the WinForms FormClosing event.

How do I provide feedback to event caller using properties in EventArgs?

My specific scenario is that there is a Controller class that does `Job A` and there are many classes requesting the `Job A` to be done. Thus, the controller is subscribed to this event on all classes.

I want to give some feedback to the caller that the job is done. The tricky part is that those classes are module-like and controller doesn't know anything about them.

My though is to include that `writable property` to the delegate of the event in order for the controller to give feedback through it. This property could somehow be invoked using reflection, which is fine in my scenario.

Answer (score 1):

you cannot define properties for delegates.
Also you do not need reflection for such a mechanism.
What you want to do is to define your "return"-properties in the `EventArgs`-derived class.

A simple such class would be:

```
public class JobEventArgs : EventArgs {
  public bool Done { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can declare your event in the class as

```
public event EventHandler<JobEventArgs> Job;
```

Usage in the method which handles the event:

```
public void DoJob(object s, JobEventArgs args) {
  // do stuff
  args.Done = true;
}
```

and in the event invoking code:

```
public void FireJobEvent() {
  var args = new JobEventArgs();

  this.Job(this, args);

  if(!args.Done) {
    // the job was not handled
  }
}
```

But frankly it rather seems like you want to do a job asynchronously with a notification when it finishes.

Which would result in syntax like..

```
class Module {
  public void JobCompleted(IAsyncResult r) {
    if(!r.IsCompleted)
      return;

    Console.WriteLine("The job has finished.");
  }

  public void ExecuteJob() {
    var job = new EventArgs<JobEventArgs>((s, a) => { this.controller.JobA(); });
    job.BeginInvoke(null, null, 
      r => 
      { 
        this.JobCompleted(r); 
        if(r.IsCompleted) 
          job.EndInvoke(r); 
      }, null);
  }
}
```